# How create read-only afc field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm new in PHP and wordpress
I created custom field "Field1"
and I want have possibility edit this filed only when I create post
how I can do it?

Comment: In the _Location_ put `Post type` `is equal to` `post` 
[Reference](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-field-group/#location)

Comment: I did it, it's not helped

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say _"only when I create post"_?

Comment: I want not have possibility update this field

Comment: Instead of `is equal to` change to `is not equal to`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant way, but hey, it works!

```
/**
*    Prevents a field from being updated from the panel in ACF.
*    Useful for business-critical fields that must only be updated internally, but still need to be visible on the admin panel.
*/
add_filter('acf/update_value/key=YOUR_FIELD_KEY/NAME', function($value, $post_id, $field) {
        $backtraces = debug_backtrace();
        foreach ($backtraces as $backtrace) {
            if ( ! empty($backtrace['function']) && $backtrace['function'] == 'update_field') {
                return $value;
            }
        }
        return get_field('YOUR_FIELD_KEY/NAME', $post_id, false);
}, 10, 3);
```